# add image as child of a CC3Node

Tags: addchild, cocos3d

I'm using Cocos3D.
There i've a list of different `CC3Node`s. I want to put an image next to each of it.
My problem is: how to create a new `CC3Node` and add it as a Child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to doing something like this:

```
CC3PlaneNode *imageNode = [CC3PlaneNode nodeWithName:@"One Plane Node on 3D Object"];
[imageNode populateAsCenteredRectangleWithSize: CGSizeMake(200.0, 200.0)
    andTessellation:ccg(40, 40) withTexture: [CC3Texture textureFromFile:@"Your Image Address"] invertTexture: YES];
imageNode.material.specularColor = kCCC4FLightGray;
imageNode.shouldCullBackFaces = NO;
[imageNode retainVertexLocations];
[self addChild:imageNode];
```

And for doing this for each Node:

```
CC3PlaneNode *newImageNode = [imageNode copyWithName:@"New Node Name"];
...
[self addChild:newImageNode];
```

At the end of it, if you want to add these node each node as a child do:

```
[previousNode addChild:newNode];
```

instead of:

```
[self addChild:newNode];
```

I hope it works for you!

Comment: I tried it - but i can't see any node.. Maybe I'm making an error? http://pastebin.com/XZvYTdNJ

Comment: If you can see your objects but can't see these images, maybe you need to change my objects position! Else, perhaps you did't set camera and lights correctly!

Comment: i'm setting the camera like this: CC3Camera* cam = [CC3Camera nodeWithName: @"Camera"];
 cam.location = cc3v( 0.0, 0.0, 6.0 );
 [self addChild: cam];

is there an error? i'm sorry for the formatting - don't know how to change that.

and the lamp like this:  CC3Light* lamp = [CC3Light nodeWithName: @"Lamp"];
 lamp.location = cc3v( -2.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
 lamp.isDirectionalOnly = NO;
 [cam addChild: lamp];
sorry for the formatting. i don't know how to change that.

Comment: You can use back tick for formatting your code. Can you see your objects before adding new images to world?

Comment: i can see one object. this picture is in the middle of my "parent" node.

Comment: I suggest you set the camera location to `cc3v(0,0,20)`. I think you are so close to objects. Also, I suggest you work on the HelloWorld demo and try to change that to your world, it works very well!

Comment: it seems like getting the wrong location of the subnodes. e.g. -17,4,-3. my main model is at 0,0,0. and it's not possible to add the image as child to the subnodes - only if i add it as a child of the main POD, it's visible..

Comment: Of course not! When you add a new child to node, Cocos3d set the center of child on the center of its parent. I think it is better for you to see this [code](https://sites.google.com/site/rajabivaramini/mycode/JustTest3DWorld.m?attredirects=0) which I wrote for you. It is just updated HelloWorld Demo. You can replace it into the HelloWorld Demo and run it.

Comment: this works fine - thank you very much! i'll try to integrate it in my application!